# PostgreSQL: List dependent rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade

How can I see which entries depend on a given entry using PostgreSQL ? (dependent meaning "having a foreign key referencing the entry").

Basically, I want to check which entries might be cascaded when I `DELETE` a given entry of a table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM dependent_table WHERE reference_key=@given_reference_key`? Or you don't know the dependent_table name / might have multiple dependent tables?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/ddl-depend.html

Comment: @NoxHarmonium: please do not link to totally outdated manuals.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev : Well, I'd like to be able to do it for all tables at once.

Comment: @NoxHarmonium: Like a_horse said, [link to the *current* manual](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108714/169168) if you don't want to address a specific version: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-depend.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see all actual *rows* depending via fk constraint, identify the columns with the tools described below.

Where foreign key constraints are defined with [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html), depending rows will be deleted (possibly cascading the `DELETE` to more *depending* tables).

Where foreign key constraints are defined with `ON DELETE SET NULL` / `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`, only the value in the columns will be reset to `NULL` / default value.

Else a `DELETE` on rows with dependent rows would fail with an exception.

Then run queries like the following on the identified tables / columns:

```
SELECT f.tbl_fk_id, f.col_fk
FROM   tbl_fk f
JOIN   tbl t ON f.col_fk = t.col
AND    <same condition as DELETE here>;
```

---

[pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) supplies this feature:

[image: Dependents]

Pick the the object in the object browser to the left and chose the dependents pane top right.

pgAdmin uses a couple of queries to the system catalog to assemble the list. You could log the commands issued if you want to build a query yourself.

Also, when deleting an object where you are not completely sure about dependents, try a plain `DROP` first (without `CASCADE`). You will get an error message if any dependent exists ...

And finally, but **proceed with caution!**, you can [*start a transaction*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-begin.html) and just issue the command:

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE tbl CASCADE;
```

Then, if you like what you see:

```
COMMIT;
```

If you don't:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

And it will be like it never happened. ;)

You will see something like this:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 4 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to constraint tbl1_tbl_id_fkey on table myschema.tbl1
drop cascades to constraint tbl_winner_tbl_id_fkey on table myschema.tbl_foo
drop cascades to constraint bar_tbl_id_fkey on table myschema.bar
drop cascades to constraint tbl1_tbl_id_fkey on table x.tbl1

Query returned successfully with no result in 47 ms.
```

Comment: I think he wants to see the **rows** that will be deleted, not the dependen tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ah, re-reading the question, you're probably right, thanks. I added a paragraph to get to actual rows.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to get the information "drop cascades ..." (NOTICE) without actually using the DELETE command, the BEGIN/ROLLBACK is a good idea though.

Answer (score 2):

You can query this directly from the PostgreSQL system catalog:

```
SELECT
  depending.relname as depending_table,
  referenced.relname as referenced_table
FROM pg_catalog.pg_depend d
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint fkey ON fkey.oid=d.objid AND fkey.contype='f'
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class depending ON depending.oid=fkey.conrelid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class referenced ON referenced.oid=d.refobjid
WHERE fkey.confdeltype='c'             -- just cascading deletes
  AND referenced.oid != depending.oid  -- ignoring reflexive dependencies
  AND referenced.relkind='r'           -- tables only
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/69be1/31) and the relevant documentation:

- [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-depend.html) for learning about dependencies
- [pg_constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) for learning about foreign keys
- [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-class.html) for learning about tables

Extending this to tell you the columns involved is left as an exercise for the reader. (Hint: [pg_attribute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html).)

Comment: Note that the system catalogs are not guaranteed to be compatible between major versions, and have repeatedly changed in incompatible ways in the past. If at all possible use `information_schema` instead.

Comment: This query works as-is against PostgreSQL as old as 8.0, and requires only one minor change to work with 7.x (the check to determine if deletes cascade). You're right that it's nonstandard, but `pg_catalog` really doesn't change that often. (It's also possible that I've gotten in the habit of querying it for info that's not present in the standard views...)

Comment: The query doesn't do exactly what I wanted (list of rows, not tables), but still is helpful to check dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers use `pg_catalog`, which is OK but can incompatibly change between major versions of PostgreSQL. Wherever possible you should use [the `information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM  information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc 
USING (constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name);
```

See:

- [`referential_constraints`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-referential-constraints.html)
- [`constraint_column_usage`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-constraint-column-usage.html)
- [`constraint_table_usage`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-constraint-column-usage.html)

Comment: I haven't actually used `pg_catalog` here - but I might have if I'd gone into detail. `information_schema` objects are often *much* slower to query. They are just (sometimes very complex) views on underlying `pg_catalog` objects, often involving lots of tables irrelevant for your query. `information_schema` is standardized and should remain stable across major versions, even across databases (that implement it). So it certainly has its uses. But the Postgres team doesn't change `pg_catalog` tables lightly either. For ad-hoc queries I always use `pg_catalog`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Good point. I was assuming, probably incorrectly, that the intention was to embed the query into an application or tool. If it's ad-hoc then pg_catalog is certainly the way to go (and usually easier to query).

Comment: For illustration compare your (seemingly simple) query with @willglynn's (seemingly complex) query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` ..